# The button is not added via a variable in the TEXT method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a task sheet. I dynamically add items to the list along with the delete button, but the button is not displayed. Why?
I can certainly write the code differently, but why does this code not work?

```js
$(function() { 
  
  $("#button").click(function() { 
    var text = $("#text").val(); 
    if(text != "")
    {
      var del = $("<input type='button' value='X'></input>").text();
      //var item = $("<li></li>").text(text + del);  
      var item = $("<li></li>").text(text + del); // DONT WORK! WHY?
      $("ul").append(item);
    }
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Введите текст: 
  <input id="text" type="text"></input>
  <input id="button" type="submit"></input>
</div>
<div class="ul">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**With this code I want to achieve this result. But I can not. Who will help explain where I'm wrong?**

```html
<li>Some Text <input type='button' value='X'></input></li>
```

Comment: What isn't working?  del will be blank as that element has no inner text.  `text()` returns the text between <></>, not the value="".  `val()` returns the value="".  You can always refer to the http://api.jquery.com if a method doesn't seem to be doing what you think it should

Comment: Also `#text` not having a value="" set, it will also be blank using val() on it.

Comment: `var item = $("<li></li>").text(text).append("<input type='button' value='X'></input>");`

Comment: var item = $("<li></li>").text(text + del); // DONT WORK! WHY? Only text from the field is added, but not a button!

Comment: Why would a button be added?  If you are trying to clarify your question, please edit your question to do so.  `text()` will never add a button.  text adds exactly that, a text node.  However in your case neither of your variables are a button.  They are both strings.  Look again at how you are defining them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue stemmed from not appending the delete button to the list item reference. As it's written I can add a list item to the `ul` but the button's delete `button` element was never attached to the list item.

Second, I removed `.text()` from `var del = $("<input type='button' value='X'></input>").text();`.

Here's my full solution.

```js
$(function() { 
  
  $("#button").click(function() { 
    var text = $("#text").val(); 
    if(text != "")
    {
      // Creating elements
      var deleteBtn = $("<input type='button' value='X'></input>");
      var item = $("<li></li>").text(text);
      
      // Appending elements
      item.append(deleteBtn);
      $("ul").append(item);
    }
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Введите текст: 
  <input id="text" type="text"></input>
  <input id="button" type="submit"></input>
</div>
<div class="ul">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `$("<input type='button' value='X'></input>").text()` returns `undefined`.

Try this:

```
   $(function() { 

      $("#button").click(function() { 
        var text = $("#text").val(); 
        if(text != "")
        {
          var delHTML = "<input type='button' value='X'></input>";

          var item = $("<li></li>").html(text + delHTML); 
          $("ul").append(item);
        }

      });

    });
```

Comment: Dont work! I get it:  "Some Text<input type='button' value='X'></input>"

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to change the text on the HTML method :)